# Jquery fadeIn() with opacity:0 or visibility:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

Simple Question: I have a div that I want to **fadein** without using `display:none` on the `div` and `css`, because it gets rid of the `div`, instead of hiding it, making the elements below it move up.

When I use `opacity:0` or `visibility:hidden`, `fadein` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$.fadeTo()` to change `opacity` instead of `display` the same way you would with `$.fadeIn()`.

You can also just toggle a class that changes `opacity` and use `transition` in CSS to handle the "fade" effect.

```js
$('#fadeto').fadeTo(1000,1);
$('#css').addClass('visible');
```

```css
#fadeto {
  opacity: 0;
}
#css {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
#css.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo</div>
<div id="fadeto">fadeto</div>
<div>foo</div>
<div id="css">css</div>
<div>foo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, if you just want to fade out without changes to display properties, you could use the following:

```
$element.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
```

For example:

```js
$('#fade').click(function(){
    $('#fadeout').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
})
```

```css
#fadeout{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: blue;
     color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fade">Fade out now</button>
<br />
<div id="fadeout">I'm visible atm</div>
<div>some other stuff</div>
```